# Mariadb nodejs connecor placeholder for table name

Tags: node.js, mariadb-connector-c

I have tables 'ranking' and 'rankingprev' and I would like to show them on same webpage.
(a) code without placeholder working

```
  pool.query("select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by MName) as Rownum, MName, Tbp,Tgp,Tpp from members inner join ranking on members.id=Member_id and Rank='NM'")
```

(b) code using placeholder gives sql syntax error (error 1064)

```
  pool.query("select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by MName) as Rownum, MName, Tbp,Tgp,Tpp from members inner join ? on members.id=Member_id and Rank='NM'", 'ranking')
```

Used placeholder in where clause without any problem

```
  pool.query("select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by MName) as Rownum, MName, Tbp,Tgp,Tpp from members inner join ranking on members.id=Member_id and Rank=?", 'NM')
```

have looked at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connector-nodejs-promise-api/#placeholder and googled around but could not resolve. Could I do (b) and what is going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The question is somewhat short, do you mean replacing `?` with the provided argument in the function?

Comment: Yes in (b). Replace ? by 'ranking' which is table name